# hibernate - how to JoinColumn an EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate

Situation: I have a masterDB and a library1DB and library2DB.

library1DB and library2DB are two separate database but has the same schema because each library must have their own database. Now we have a masterDB, this is an aggregated version of all the data in all libraries (library1DB and library2DB), still taking note of their respective ids and mapping them to their library id.

Here's I want my tables to be structured:
book
- book_id
- library_id
- title
- shelf_id
shelf
- shelf_id
- library_id
- book_id
- description

I have these models:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BookKey bookKey;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "SHELF_ID", referencedColumnName = "SHELF_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "LIBRARY_ID", referencedColumnName = "LIBRARY_ID")
    })
    private ObjectA objectA;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "ANOTHER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ANOTHER_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "LIBRARY_ID", referencedColumnName = "LIBRARY_ID")
    })
    private ObjectB objectB;    

    @Column
    private String title;

}

@Embeddable
public class BookKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "BOOK_ID")
    private long bookId;
    @Column(name = "LIBRARY_ID")
    private long libraryId;
}
```

But I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Book column: library_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

I've tried using @IdClass instead of @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId, and I got this:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException:  Table [book] contains physical column name [libraryId] represented by different logical column names: [libraryId], [LIBRARY_ID]
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should add `insert="false", update="false"` for the second mapped column `library_id`.
Try this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "LIBRARY_ID", referencedColumnName = "LIBRARY_ID",
            insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

Comment: It works when I only have ObjectA, it works.  But when I have ObjectB, I'm encountering the same exception again.

Comment: You have already mapped the column `library_id` in the object `BookKey`. So you should add `insertable = false, updatable = false` for all other places where you map the same column.

Comment: When you set insertable and updatable to false does that mean you can't modify Library_ID or you can't modify anything in the nested table?

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the same problem. If you add insert="false", update="false" only to one, you will get an exception stating that you mixed writable and non-writables and that this is not allowed. The following works:

I solved it using the **@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns**, try this (from another example):

```
@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(value = {
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "country_code"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "zip_code", referencedColumnName = "code")
})
private Zip zip;

@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(value = {
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "country_code"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "state_code", referencedColumnName = "state_code"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "city_name", referencedColumnName = "name")
})
private City city;
```

from [Hibernate throws AnnotationException on column used by multiple overlapping foreign keys](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6221)